# This stored procedure is showing subquery error in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery, sql-server-2017

```
ALTER PROCEDURE daily_routine
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp_stats (i_count, r_count, s_count, w_count, n_count, z_count, t_count, 
                            p_hour, p_location, p_location_count, 
                            p_location_percentage, p_hour_percentage, d_date)
    VALUES (
       (SELECT SUM(i_count) as i_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(r_count) as r_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(s_count) as s_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(w_count) as w_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(n_count) as n_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(z_count) as z_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT SUM(t_count) as t_count FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT time_range AS p_hour FROM temp_h_stats 
        WHERE t_count = (SELECT MAX(t_count) FROM temp_h_stats)),
       (SELECT p_location AS p_location FROM temp_hourly_stats 
        WHERE t_count = (SELECT MAX(t_count) FROM temp_hourly_stats)),
       (SELECT p_location_count AS p_location_count FROM temp_h_stats 
        WHERE p_location_count = (SELECT MAX(p_location_count) FROM temp_h_stats)),
       (SELECT MAX(p_location_percentage) AS p_location_percentage FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT (MAX(t_count) * 100) / SUM(t_count) AS p_hour_percentage FROM temp_h_stats),
       (SELECT DATEADD(DD, -1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS recorded_date))
END
```

The output of this query is an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And I also implemented the same procedure as this one in SQL Server 2017 with same query only the table names are different, and it is working but I don't know why this procedure is not working.

Comment: Why so many selects from the same table?

Comment: It is not a same table I am taking sum of data from one table and inserting into another table check it one more time

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be better:

```
ALTER Procedure daily_routine
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @MaxCounT_h_stats BIGINT
       ,@MaxCounT_hourly_states BIGINT
       ,@MaxLocation_Count BIGINT;

SET @MaxCounT_h_stats = (select max(t_count) from temp_h_stats);
SET @MaxCounT_hourly_states = (select max(t_count) from temp_hourly_stats);
SET @MaxLocation_Count = (select max(p_location_count) from temp_h_stats);

INSERT INTO temp_stats(i_count,r_count,s_count,w_count,n_count,z_count,t_count,p_hour,p_location,p_location_count,p_location_percentage,p_hour_percentage,d_date)
SELECT SUM(i_count) as i_count
      ,SUM(r_count) as r_count
      ,SUM(s_count) as s_count
      ,SUM(w_count) as w_count
      ,SUM(n_count) as n_count
      ,SUM(z_count) as z_count
      ,SUM(t_count) as t_count
      ,MAX(IIF(t_count = @MaxCounT_h_stats, time_range, NULL) as p_hour
      ,MAX(IIF(t_count = @MaxCounT_hourly_states, p_location, NULL) as p_location
      ,MAX(IIF(p_location_count = @MaxLocation_Count, p_location_count, NULL) as p_location_count
      ,MAX(p_location_percentage) as p_location_percentage
      ,(MAX(t_count)*100)/SUM(t_count) as p_hour_percentage
      ,DATEADD(DD, -1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as recorded_date)
FROM temp_h_stats

END
```

Your main issue is you are using too many sub queries in case you can do this with one table read. One of these:

```
(SELECT time_range as p_hour from temp_h_stats where t_count= (select max(t_count) from temp_h_stats)),
(SELECT p_location as p_location from temp_hourly_stats where t_count= (select max(t_count) from temp_hourly_stats)),
(SELECT p_location_count as p_location_count from temp_h_stats where p_location_count = (select max(p_location_count) from temp_h_stats)),
```

is returning more the one value, so you are getting this error. If you do not like to use my variation just add an aggregate function on the above statements.

Comment: Can,t I apply distinct??

Comment: @UtkarshMishra Well, it depends - if all of the values are same, it will work - if you have even two different values, the query will fail again.

Comment: @UtkarshMishra If you want to get all values from this queries you can use `STRING_AGG` - it will perform concatenation of the values.

Comment: Sorry but it is not, how can I use Distinct here?

Comment: Its not taking IFF as a function of sql server

Comment: @UtkarshMishra True, SQL Server doesn't support the IIF function. You can use the CASE structure instead

Comment: @UtkarshMishra You said you are using SQL Server 2017 - `IIF` function is support in this edition. If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 or previous the function is not supported and you can use `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Yes sir but I read that sometimes duplicate may arise problem so can I use distinct here with all column names??

Comment: @gotqn Sir I removed where condition from my procedure again its showing the same sub query error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clearly that the subqueries that are getting the maximums are returning multiple values.

The following code assumes that `temp_hourly_stats` is really `temp_h_stats`.  The code could easily be adjusted to handle two different tables, but the names look very similar.

I would recommend a single query and window functions:

```
INSERT INTO temp_stats (i_count, r_count, s_count, w_count, n_count, z_count, t_count ,p_hour, p_location, p_location_count, p_location_percentage, p_hour_percentage, d_date)
    SELECT SUM(i_count) as i_count,
           SUM(r_count) as r_count,
           SUM(s_count) as s_count,
           SUM(w_count) as w_count,
           SUM(n_count) as n_count,
           SUM(z_count) as z_count
           SUM(t_count) as t_count,
           MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_t_count = 1 THEN time_range END) as p_hour,
           MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum_t_count = 1 THEN p_location END) as p_location
           MAX(p_location_count) as p_location_count
           MAX(p_location_percentage) as p_location_percentage
           (MAX(t_count) * 100) / SUM(t_count) as p_hour_percentage
           DATEADD(day, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as recorded_date)
    FROM (SELECT ths.*,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_count DESC) as seqnum_t_count
          FROM temp_h_stats ths
         ) t;
```

Note that I have simplified this logic:

```
  (SELECT p_location_count AS p_location_count
   FROM temp_h_stats 
   WHERE p_location_count = (SELECT MAX(p_location_count) FROM temp_h_stats)
  ),
```

To:

```
MAX(p_location_count)
```

Comment: This one is useful